# Setting Core Data property value with float type

Tags: iphone, core-data

In a test iPhone app I am developing, I am trying to set the value of a float field in my Core Data model. The compiler is giving me an incompatible type error even though both the data type specified in my method is a float and the data type in model is a float.

This is the first project where I am using Core Data instead of SQLite 3.

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(NSString *)titleTxt withAmount:(float)amount andDueDate:(NSDate *)due {
[newManagedObject setValue:amount forKey:@"amountDue"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to make an NSNumber with the float.

Comment: I thought it'd be something of that nature. Thanks for the quick response.